# Calculate hour range between dates in python

Tags: python, datetime

How can I find out the hours in a date range? I'm currently calculating and printing the dates between two given dates.

```
from datetime import timedelta as td, datetime

d1 = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
d2 = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d')

def get_delta(d1, d2):
    delta = d2 - d1
    return delta

delta = get_delta(d1,d2)
for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    print d1 + td(days=i)
```

**Current output:**

```
2016-04-22
2016-04-23
2016-04-24
2016-04-25
2016-04-26
2016-04-27
2016-04-28
...
```

**Expected output:**

```
2016-04-22 00:00:00
2016-04-22 01:00:00
2016-04-22 02:00:00
2016-04-22 03:00:00
2016-04-22 04:00:00
2016-04-22 05:00:00
2016-04-22 06:00:00
2016-04-22 07:00:00
...
```

Comment: What is get_delta()? Are d1 and d2 datetime.datetime objects or datetime.date objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are incrementing the time by days and not hours, `timedelta(days=i)` and not `timedelta(hours=i)`

```
from datetime import timedelta as td, datetime

start_date = '2016-01-01'
end_date = '2016-01-02'
d1 = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
d2 = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d')

def get_delta(d1, d2):
    delta = d2 - d1
    return delta

delta = get_delta(d1,d2)
for i in range(delta.days * 24 + 1):
    print d1 + td(hours=i)
```

Output:

```
2016-01-01 00:00:00
2016-01-01 01:00:00
...
...
2016-01-01 23:00:00
2016-01-02 00:00:00
```

Comment: Won't this always go through the entire last day, rather than only to the hour in end_date?

Comment: Yes, it will. I just tried to stay as close as possible to the original code snippet.

Comment: Fair enough. And I suppose as long as the OP sticks with getting the dates from the format '%Y-%m-%d' it won't be an issue. Figured I'd point it out though.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters this will go through entire days only, what if we wanted to go to the end_date's hour? thanks

Comment: @Eric I am not sure if I understood your question correctly but you could add the hour to your `end_date` and adjust the `datetime` object format accordingly. Is this the same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52841611/getting-number-of-hours-between-a-date-time-range-in-python

Answer (score 2):

For readability, to have a clear semantics of what happens in the edge cases, you could define `date_range()` function that is similar to the builtin `range()` function:

```
def date_range(start, end, step):
    while start < end:
        yield start
        start += step
```

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

HOUR = timedelta(hours=1)

def parse(date_string):
    '''Parse *date_string* in the %Y-%m-%d format.'''
    return datetime(*map(int, date_string.split('-')))

for dt in date_range(parse(start_date), parse(end_date), HOUR):
    print(dt)
```

Note: `end_date + ' 00:00:00` is not present in the output. `date_range()` behaves like `range()` where `end` is not included. You could pass `parse(end_date) + HOUR` to include the  `end_date`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the python docs for timedelta objects:

> Only days, seconds and microseconds are stored internally

So if you want to get the hours you'll have to convert it from the seconds.

Something like:

```
for i in range(delta.seconds / 3600 + delta.days * 24):
    print d1 + td(seconds=3600 * i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import datetime

d1 = datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 28)
d2 = d1 + datetime.timedelta(days = 2)

delta = (d2 - d1).total_seconds()/3600
for i in range(int(delta)):
    print(d1 + datetime.timedelta(hours=i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
datelist = pd.date_range(start = pd.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0),
                         end = pd.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 0),
                         freq = "H")
```