# Getting number of Hours between a Date-Time Range in Python

Tags: python, datetime

So I'm trying to print the total hours in intervals between a start date and an end date in python as follows:

```
@app.route('/test/')
def test():

date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
start_date_time = datetime.strptime("2018-10-16 07:00:00", date_format)
end_date_time = datetime.strptime("2018-10-18 22:00:00", date_format)

def daterange(start_date_time, end_date_time):
    for n in range(int ((end_date_time - start_date_time).days)):
        yield start_date_time + timedelta(n)

for single_date in daterange(start_date_time, end_date_time):
    def get_delta(start_date_time, end_date_time):
        delta = end_date_time - start_date_time
        return delta

# Split time in hours
delta = get_delta(start_date_time,end_date_time)
for i in range(delta.days * 24 + 1): # THIS IS ONLY CALCULATING 24HRS FROM TIME GIVEN START TIME NOT TILL THE SELECTED END TIME SO I'M ONLY GETTING AN EXACT 24 HOUR RANGE
    currtime = start_date_time + timedelta(hours=i)

    print (currtime)
return ("done")
```

By This i'm only managing to get the first 24 Hours from the selected date, but I wish to keep on counting and get all hours till the selected end date.

Comment: You can always use `.total_seconds() / 3600` https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be overthinking it.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
start_date_time = datetime.strptime("2018-10-16 07:00:00", date_format)
end_date_time = datetime.strptime("2018-10-18 22:00:00", date_format)

def get_delta(l, r):
    return abs(int((l-r).total_seconds())) / 3600

for h in range(int(get_delta(start_date_time, end_date_time))):
    print((start_date_time + timedelta(0, h*3600)).strftime(date_format))
```

Comment: But this just gives me the total amount of hours between both dates and won't print hour intervals... thanks for your help

Comment: Ahh. That's an odd thing to do, but OK. Edited.

Comment: ok this seems to work well, thanks for your answer. I will mark as correct, but I have one question if you can help, is it possible to loop within the dates after this and do a function for each day, ex: 16/10/2018 > do something ... continue... 17/10/2018 > do something .... continue ... 18/10/2018 > do something. Thanks again

Comment: Yes - you could use something like `new_time = start_date_time + timedelta(0, h*3600)` in the loop. Then `if new_time.hour == 0:` will run code every time there's a new day.